# Delete subdirectories in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to delete all subdirectories named .svn from all levels of a directory tree, without touching anything else? rd/s and del/s don't seem to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for /r /d %i in (.svn) do rd /s /q "%i"`

Use `%%i` instead of `%i` in batch files, and make sure your current directory is at the top of the hierarchy you want to start from.

Edit: Just noticed that this will also catch folders that *end* in `.svn`, not just those that are named `.svn`.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to a batch file. Do make a backup of the files first.

```
@for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad *.svn 2^>NUL') do rd /s /q "%%a"
```

Comment: Note that if you run this command from Command Prompt then you need to replace the double percent signs with single ones.

Answer (score 3):

If your hard disk is NTFS, you can use the free [Everything search engine](http://www.voidtools.com/).

After it's installed, right click on the directory and select "Search Everything...".
Then type *.svn to see all such named files and sub-directories.
Click on the first in the list, then type ctrl-A to select the whole list, then type Del to delete them all.

Comment: Wouldn't this also work with windows' own search function?

Comment: @Console: Windows' search is notorious for having hiccups.

Answer (score 3):

I see this question asked all the time for users of SVN, you do NOT need a special script to get rid of those pesky .svn folders.

I don't know what platform you are on, but you can use:

```
 svn export
```

To make SVN make a copy of your working copy without the .svn folders.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Subversion.html

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run powershell one liner:

```
dir "PATH" -rec|?{($_.psiscontainer)-and($_.name-eq'.svn')}|rm -fo
```